# PostgreSQL configure Every Insert Happens on 1st position

Tags: database, postgresql

Please Help me, to give the solution,
How Can I configure PostgreSQL, to insert every new row in the first position!

generally, every new row inserts after the previous row.
But, I need to insert a new row before the previous row.

How Can I configure PostgreSQL for that purpose?

If that's not possible then anyone please explain why ..?

Comment: There is no such thing as the "first position" of a row. Rows in a relational database have no implied sort order. If you need a guaranteed sort order, the **only** (really: the _only_) way to do that is to use `order by` when you select the rows

Comment: I have to do something when INSERT Data. not when SELECT/get data.

Comment: Again: there is no "sort order" when inserting. You can **only** define an order when SELECTing using an `order by`. There is no alternative.

Comment: Why can not do this..?